# How to find the test a data provider is providing data to?

Tags: php, reflection, phpunit

Inside a PHPUnit testcase with two or more tests using the same [`@dataProvider`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers), I want the provider to find out, which test it is providing data to. I have accomplished this using [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), but this feels wrong. Does PHPUnit provide another more standard way to achieve this? In case yes, how?

```
<?php

class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /** @dataProvider dataProvider */
    public function testA () {}

    /** @dataProvider dataProvider */
    public function testB () {}

    public function dataProvider () {

        $trace = debug_backtrace(false, 3);
        $caller = $trace[2]['args'][2];

        // $caller === 'testA' or $caller === 'testB'
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need that? If you need different data for different tests, use different providers. If there are a lot of similarities between the data, extract them into another method.

Comment: I want to automate test data management and I need a single entry point for the data retrieval from files. The data provider will not stay part of the testcase but reside inside a trait that is designed to fetch test data from the filesystem based on the testcase and the actual test that is being executed.

Comment: Then create multiple wrapper methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create individual data providers which call a base data provider. This way you know what the caller is and can still have a single entry point.

```
<?php

class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /** @dataProvider dataProviderA */
    public function testA() {}

    /** @dataProvider dataProviderB */
    public function testB() {}

    public function dataProviderA() 
    { 
        $dataProvider = $this->getProviderData();
        // Caller is A ...
        // Mutate base provider data as necessary...
    }

    public function dataProviderB() 
    { 
        $dataProvider = $this->getProviderData();
        // Caller is B ...
        // Mutate base provider data as necessary...
    }

    public function getProviderData() 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```